# Dynamically replace attribute or element values in XML using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <PLANT COLOR="@DYNAMIC_COLOR@">
        <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>4</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>@DYNAMIC_PRICE@</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT COLOR="RED" TYPE="@DYNAMIC_TYPE@">
        <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>3</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

I want to transform to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <PLANT COLOR="RED">
        <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>4</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>10</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT COLOR="RED" TYPE="HERBS">
        <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>3</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

Basically, i want to replace "@DYNAMIC_*@" attribute/element value with a predefined values. Please help!!! I can do with for each and exactly finding the values and replace it with the desired values. But i prefer to use apply template concept.

Comment: Write templates with e.g. `match="*[not(*) and matches(., '^@DYNAMIC_\w+@$')]"` and then insert the value you want (not sure whether you want to take it from one or more parameters and how you want to select it based on the dynamic part, you haven't explained that).

Comment: let's say we have 3 dynamic values my example - so, we can have 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A neat solution for this kind of problem is to transform your skeleton XML document into a stylesheet. Write a transformation that converts it to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:param name="DYNAMIC_COLOR"/>
  <xsl:param name="DYNAMIC_TYPE"/>
  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
<CATALOG>
    <PLANT COLOR="{$DYNAMIC_COLOR}">
        <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>4</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>{$DYNAMIC_PRICE}</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT COLOR="RED" TYPE="{$DYNAMIC_TYPE}">
        <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>3</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then execute this stylesheet with entry point "xsl:initial-template" and with values for the parameters. I've used XSLT 3.0 value templates here to make it a bit easier; if you want to use XSLT 2.0 you can generate xsl:value-of instructions instead.

The basic logic for the conversion is

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="z" result-prefix="xsl"/>
<xsl:variable name="params" select="distinct-values(
     (//@*|//text())[matches(., '^@.*@^')]!translate(., '@', ''))"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <z:stylesheet version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:for-each select="$params">
      <z:param name="{.}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <z:template name="xsl:initial-template">          
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </z:template>
  </z:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[matches(., '^@.*@$')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., '^@(.*)@$', '{\$$1}')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[matches(., '^@.*@$')]">
  <!-- 3.0 -->
  <!-- <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^@(.*)@$', '{\$$1}')"/> -->
  <!-- 2.0 -->
  <z:value-of select="replace(., '^@(.*)@$', '\$$1'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may need to do a bit more work if there are attributes or text nodes that contain curly braces: these need to be doubled.

Comment: thanks Micheal! But i am using XSLT 2.0, and a bit new to XSLT. I don't get this one - "if you want to use XSLT 2.0 you can generate xsl:value-of instructions instead." Please help!!!